# Enabling toolbar auto-hide when scroll after scrolling passing certain view

Tags: android, android-toolbar, android-coordinatorlayout

I am trying to implement auto-hiding feature for my toolbar using CoordinateLayout. But I also want to tweaks it a bit, so that the hide/show only works after I scroll past my imageview.

[image]

I am currently able to "turn on/off" the hide/show availability for the toolbar via AppBarLayout.LayoutParams. So right now it won't hide the toolbar if I scroll within the imageview's height and will hide if I scroll pass the imageview. The only problem is, if I scroll the layout very fast and instantly pull my finger before it pass the imageview's height the toolbar won't hide. In my opinion it is because the scrolling listener's function is called before the parameter of the toolbar's show/hide is changed to enable.

Here's the code:
ArticleActivity.java

```
public class ArticleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

private Toolbar toolbar;
private ImageView imageView;
private NestedScrollView scrollView;

private Matrix matrix;

private int imageHeight = 0;
private float scale = 0;
private boolean hideable = false;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_article);

    imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    scrollView = (NestedScrollView) findViewById(R.id.scrollView);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    matrix = new Matrix();

    DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    scale = (float) displayMetrics.widthPixels / ((float) imageView.getDrawable().getIntrinsicWidth());
    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);

    if(imageView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        imageView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                imageView.getViewTreeObserver().removeOnGlobalLayoutListener(this);
                imageHeight = imageView.getHeight();
            }
        });
    }

    if(scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().isAlive()) {
        scrollView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnScrollChangedListener(new ViewTreeObserver.OnScrollChangedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onScrollChanged() {
                int scrollY = scrollView.getScrollY();
                if(scrollY <= imageHeight) {
                    matrix.setTranslate(0, scrollY / 4);
                    matrix.postScale(scale, scale);
                    imageView.setImageMatrix(matrix);
                    if(hideable) {
                        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                        params.setScrollFlags(0);
                        toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
                        hideable = false;
                    }
                } else {
                    if(!hideable) {
                        AppBarLayout.LayoutParams params = (AppBarLayout.LayoutParams) toolbar.getLayoutParams();
                        // 1 = scroll, 4 = enterAlways, 16 = snap
                        params.setScrollFlags(21);
                        toolbar.setLayoutParams(params);
                        hideable = true;
                    }
                }
            }
        });
    }
}}
```

activity_article.xml:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"/>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/imageView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:adjustViewBounds="true"
            android:scaleType="matrix"
            android:src="@drawable/download"/>

        <TextView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_below="@id/imageView"
            android:text="What is Lorem Ipsum?"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</android.support.v4.widget.NestedScrollView>
```

What should I do to fix this? Or is there another way to achieve this? Thank you